# Accessing nodes in Perl libXML

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2, xml-libxml

I have the following Perl code, I am using LibXML:

```
 my @childnodes = $node1->childNodes();
 my $node2 = @childnodes->getNode(1); # Access first child node
```

What I want to do is to access the nodes obtained by `childNodes()` individually but my `$node2 = @childnodes->getNode(1);` doesn't work. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@childNodes` is an array of nodes. Just treat it like any other array.

```
my $node2 = $childnodes[0]; # Access first child node
```

Comment: Also note that `childNodes` returns a `XML::LibXML::NodeList` in scalar context. So replacing the array `@childnodes` with `$childnodes` should work, too.